# Angularjs2 form document sample, bootstrap.min.css not downloading

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am following the sample from anuglar document https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

In my html file header I added bootstrap.min.css reference. when I refresh the its giving 404 return code for this URL.

http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

I see file in the file system. created the project using angular-cli, running it in development mode.

why its giving 404 File Not Found return code?

thanks
SR

below answer works for me.
but from chrome network connection didn't show css getting downloaded to browser.

[image]

Comment: What version of the angular-cli are you using? meaning did you install it via `npm install -g angular-cli@webpack`?

Comment: yes, I installed latest anuglar-cli. npm install -g angular-cli@webpack with this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the version you mentioned you have in the comments above you can set a reference to a style file which will get included in your application

In `angular-cli.json` add the path to your `CSS` file in the `styles` array. You can also remove the reference you added to `index.html` because the webpack build process will add the referenced CSS file for you just by adding it to `angular-cli.json`

You can see me demo this [here](https://youtu.be/obbdFFbjLIU?t=10m59s)

Comment: This work for me. I have question, when look at network connection in the chrom, I didn't see css file getting downloaded. how css file getting downloaded to broswer?